# Opening jQuery dialog inside "display:none" iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, iframe, dialog

The situation is: on the website I have tab system implemented with iframes. There is an `<ul>` that contains `<li>`'s. Each `<li>` contains one `<iframe>`.

Like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <iframe></iframe>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

On one of the pages, a jQuery dialog is opened when certain event happens.

The problem is: if tab (`<iframe>`) is not activated (parent `<li>` element has `display:none`) and jQuery dialog is initiated, then when user returns to this tab, the dialog is located in wrong position. It's `top` and `left` attributes is set to `0`. It happens in FireFox but not in Chrome.

The only solution I found is to initiate redrawing of dialog when user switches to this page, by calling some universal function inside iframe when it's activated if this function exists on this page. But I think this solution is bad and I hope there is a better way to solve this.

Appreciate any help and sorry for my English.